# SQL Server 2012 : how do I join 2 case when clauses into 1 column?

Tags: sql-server

I need some assistance with a query. I have a table with the following info:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJtpD.png)

I need to allocate a point system for every call, calls less than 1 min, calls between 1 and 5 min , calls between 5 and 10 min and lastly calls over 10 min

Currently my query looks like this:

```
Select distinct convert (date,AIV.PSEndTime,102) as TRXDATE 
,AIV.Username
,AIV.FirstName+' '+AIV.LastName as Agent_Name
,AIV.ITypeDisplayValue
,convert (datetime,AIV.PSBeginTime,120) as PSBeginTime
,convert (datetime,AIV.PSEndTime,120) as PSEndTime
,convert(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,AIV.Talking,0),108) as [Talking]
,CASE WHEN AIV.Talking <='60' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as Less_than_1min
,CASE WHEN AIV.Talking between '61' and '300' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as Between_1_and_5_min
,CASE WHEN AIV.Talking between '301' and '600' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as Between_5_and_10_min
,CASE WHEN AIV.Talking >='601' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as More_than_10min

 From AgentInteractionsView as AIV WITH (NOLOCK)

 WHere UserName in ('TomE','MicDe','JulCa') 
and AIV.PSBeginTime > '2017-08-01'
and AIV.PSEndTime < '2017-09-01'
group by
convert (date,AIV.PSEndTime,102)
    ,AIV.Username
,AIV.FirstName+' '+AIV.LastName
,AIV.ITypeDisplayValue,AIV.DIDisplayValue
,convert (datetime,(DATEADD(hour,2,AIV.PSBeginTime)),120)
,convert (datetime,(DATEADD(hour,2,AIV.PSEndTime)),120)
,convert(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,AIV.Talking,0),108)
,AIV.Talking
```

And this actually worked however I noticed that when the Column "talking" was Null it would not give me a result so I added a new query:

```
,CASE WHEN AIV.Talking <='60' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as Less_than_1min
,CASE WHEN AIV.Talking = null THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as Less_than_1min
```

Hoping that these would result in a single column, but of course it gave me 2 columns with the same heading.

I want to join these two queries into 1 column, for example

```
,CASE WHEN AIV.Talking = null THEN 1 
ELSE (CASE WHEN AIV.Talking <='60' THEN 1 ELSE 0) end 
as Less_than_1min
```

am I missing something ( obviously) or am I expecting too much from SQL :)

Comment: You don't need to use CASE to deal with NULL values, there is ISNULL and COALESCE. - COALESCE(AIV.Talking,0) if it is NULL that would return 0 instead of NULL and wouldn't break your logic as it would be less that 60.

Comment: Thanks how ever I want the Null cells to show as 1 in the 'Less_than_1min' colunm

Comment: That is what the above would do if you configured it correctly to return what is required so it can be compared in your case expression. 0 <= 60, so would return a 1. Have answered so I can give more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the assistance I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong.

As the Time is and Integer Showing the number of Seconds I came to this solution :)

```
Select CASE WHEN AIV.Talking <='60' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as Less_than_1min 
,CASE WHEN AIV.Talking between '61' and '300' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as Between_1_and_5_min ,
CASE WHEN AIV.Talking between '301' and '600' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as Between_5_and_10_min 
,CASE WHEN AIV.Talking >='601' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as More_than_10min
```

I really hope that this helps someone else in future :)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can use ISNULL or COALESCE to handle a NULL value, example code:

```
DECLARE @time   TIME;
SET     @time = NULL;

SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(@time,'00:00:01') <= '00:01:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Test_Time;
```

The above code returns a 1, as does:

```
DECLARE @time   TIME;
SET     @time = '00:00:01';

SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(@time,'00:00:01') <= '00:01:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Test_Time;
```

And the below returns a 0:

```
DECLARE @time   TIME;
SET     @time = '00:02:01';

SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(@time,'00:00:01') <= '00:01:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Test_Time;
```

As does:

```
DECLARE @time   TIME;
SET     @time = NULL;

SELECT CASE WHEN @time <= '00:01:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Test_Time;
```

As the value is NULL, it cannot evaluate, so returns false.

So when using COALESCE, I just make sure that what I set the value to be if it is NULL fits in with the CASE expression logic, to return what I require.